# Origin/meaning of common surname Naiman (or similar)

Tags: names, etymology

What is the origin and/or meaning of the common Jewish surname Naiman (or Neiman, Najman, etc.)?

According to [this site](http://genealogy.familyeducation.com/surname-origin/naiman) the common Jewish name is of Germanic origin, meaning "Newcomer".

However, I've also seen the name "Neeman", occasionally spelled, and almost always pronounced, "Ne'eman" (sounds like the Hebrew word for "Faithful").  We also now have a newcomer (no pun intended) [with the name Neaman](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/2022/joshua-neaman).

Is it possible that these names are related?  Is Naiman perhaps a Germanification of Ne'eman?  Or is Ne'eman perhaps an Hebraicization of Naiman?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Kazakh - Naiman and I'm neither Jewish or German. First Naimans were originated in East Kazakhstan before mongols conquered our land. All my ancestors were from the Turkic speaking tribe - Naiman. I'm just wondered and it is so much confusion when Jews have the same surname. Before the soviet union all Kazakhs in Kazakhstan used names of tribes as surnames. However, when the soviets came they pushed locals to withdraw their tribal surnames and change them into russian sounding names with 'eva','ev' at the end. This is what my great grandparents told me. Some tribal surnames are: Naiman, Aday, Kerei, Alan, Argyn, Kagan. After the collapse of the USSR some Kazakh returned back (or returning) to their original tribal surnames. I'm thinking as well, to change my long russified surname into Naiman. So, I'm not Jewish, but it is still interesting how our tribal name came to them.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Thanks for the answer. Consider learning more about the site from the following short Beginners' Guide: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775.